# How to get particular document data with id ? | AngularFire 5.1.1 | Cloud Firestore | Documents

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire5

I am using Data access service to get the data from firebase firestore.

How to use snapshotChanges()method for getting particular document data with id

```
getProduct(id: number): Observable<Product> {
    this.productsDocuments = this.angularfirestore.doc<Product>('products/' + id);
    this.product = this.productsDocuments.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes => changes.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Product;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      }))
    );
    return this.product
```

I want this.product returns the document value and document id

Thank You!!

Comment: The return of `this.product` will include the id. So `this.product.id` is the id of the document. To acces it with the return you have to use `this.service.getProduct().subscribe((product) => { console.log(product.id) })`

Comment: @Swoox - Thank you for your reply your approach will work, but snapshotChanges() not work, the error Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Action<DocumentSnapshot<Product>>'.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A document is simply an object `{[field]: value}`
and a collection is a container for documents `[document]`.

You are trying to get a single document/object and the problem is that you cannot map to it directly.  I think that you want to get the entire collection, and then map over all of the documents.

```
getProduct(id: number): Observable<Product> {
    const productsDocuments = this.db.doc<Product>('products/' + id);
    return productsDocuments.snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(changes => {
          const data = changes.payload.data();
          const id = changes.payload.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        }))
  }
```

for a collection

```
getProduct(id: string): Observable<Product[]> {
    const productsDocuments = this.db.collection<Product[]>('products');
    return productsDocuments.snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(changes => changes.map(({ payload: { doc } }) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          const id = doc.id
          return { id, ...data };
        })),
        map((products) => products.find(doc => doc.id === id)))
  }
```