# AngularFire ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(31,43): error TS2559: Type '"name"' has no properties in common with type 'GetOptions'

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I try to get data from my Firestore Document. Therefore i created this:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 title = 'HEIMATVOLL';

  blogeintrag = BLOGEINTRAG;
  selectedBlogeintrag: Blogeintrag;
  private itemDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<MyObjectInterface>;
 item: Observable<MyObjectInterface>;
 constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
this.itemDoc = afs.doc<MyObjectInterface>('Test/bA2cv4cJ3lvJ2f8ybTDM');
this.item = this.itemDoc.valueChanges();
 }


ngOnInit() {
console.log("fasdf1",this.itemDoc.get('name'));
}

onSelect(blogeintrag: Blogeintrag): void {
this.selectedBlogeintrag = blogeintrag;
}
```

}

in my OnInit method i try to print out the value of the documents key "name". Unfortunately i receive this error :

> error TS2559: Type '"name"' has no properties in common with type 'GetOptions'.

And the log says "undefined".

Would be great if someone could explain how i can get a certain value.

Comment: If you look at the type afs.doc<MyObjectInterface> will return, it's not just <MyObjectInterface>. Doing a quick search, there are a lot of references on how to do this. Here is another stackoverflow answer explaining https://stackoverflow.com/a/54071543/10747134 .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get particular document data with id ? | AngularFire 5.1.1 | Cloud Firestore | Documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54070697/how-to-get-particular-document-data-with-id-angularfire-5-1-1-cloud-firest)